# Using OR( || ) in CAlculate function is not working

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, business-intelligence

I am learning powerbi DAX. I have measure to calculate totals sales for **1996 or 1997.**

```
23. 1996 or 1997 = CALCULATE([3.Total Sales],DimDate[Year]="1997"||DimDate[Year]="1996")
```

In table I got distribution as,

[image]

The measure  `23. 1996 or 1997`  is showing total sales different for year 1996 and 1997. I am following the same tutor guide and he is getting the different result using this same measure.

[image]

Here the measure is showing same sales amount in each row. The datatype I am using in Year is **"Text"**. Is it the issue or anything?

Comment: What amount you plan to show, I think system is showing correctly, but your concept is different?

Comment: Are you using Columns from different tables in both visuals? Share you PBI file to get any further assistance.

Comment: Compare your data model to the tutor's.  I suspect you have a relationship that your tutor does not (or, as @AntrikshSharma suggests, you might not be using the same columns in your visuals).